# Why there is an empty yellow box in mod election?

Tags: support, moderator-election

In the [community moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9), under `Please participate...` advice I see a yellow box also separated from the description via the gray bar.

[image]

[image: div]

It looks like something will show up there, but while there's nothing here, what's the purpose of showing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually, that's going to be filled in with statistics on how the election played out. Observe the contents of the yellow box in the previous election: https://stackoverflow.com/election/8

Before then, it'll be filled with a bit of text explaining the current status of the election; something like:

- Nomination phase: *Nominations close July 24th*
- Primary phase: *Primary closes July 28th*
- Election phase: *Election closes August 1st*

Currently, the election has neither ended nor is in any normal phase; as it has yet to start, *there's no status to display*. Come back in an hour and check it again...

Comment: But while there's nothing here, what's the purpose of showing it?

Comment: See edit - essentially there are multiple things that *can* be displayed there, but since the election hasn't started yet none of them qualify.

Comment: I understand what is going to be shown here, but why not hide the yellow box while there's no status to display?

Comment: It makes the code simpler to do it this way. The page is not particularly optimized for use pre-election.